# Extracting bit positions in a union of 16 bits in C

Tags: c, unions

I want to declare a `union` in C which mainly contains a `16-bit` word, and I should be able to read/write the **LSP** `7 bits` and `8th bit` separately for each byte in the `16-bit` word, so I declared something like:

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t full_8_char_byte[2];
    uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_0 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
    uint8_t parity_bit_word_0 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
    uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_1 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
    uint8_t parity_bit_word_1 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
} ip_char_t;
```

Now, when I write `7-bit` values to these individual bytes in the `16-bit` word:

```
x.full_8_char_byte[0] = 0x7E;
x.full_8_char_byte[1] = 0x7E;
```

---

**The following simple program:**

```
int main()
{
    ip_char_t x;
    x.full_8_char_byte[0] = 0x7E;
    x.full_8_char_byte[1] = 0x7E;

    printf("%c   %c\n", x.full_8_char_byte[1], x.full_8_char_byte[0]);
    printf("%u   %u\n", x.full_8_char_byte[1], x.full_8_char_byte[0]);
    printf("%X   %X\n\n", x.full_8_char_byte[1], x.full_8_char_byte[0]);

    printf("%c   %c\n", x.ascii_7_bits_word_1, x.ascii_7_bits_word_0);
    printf("%u   %u\n", x.ascii_7_bits_word_1, x.ascii_7_bits_word_0);
    printf("%X   %X\n\n", x.ascii_7_bits_word_1, x.ascii_7_bits_word_0);

    printf("%d   %d\n", x.parity_bit_word_1, x.parity_bit_word_0);
    return 0;
}
```

**gives the correct output as follows:**

```
~   ~  
126   126   
7E   7E

~   ~ 
126   126 
7E   7E

0   0
```

**but when I initialized `x.full_8_char_byte[1] to a 8-bit value`:**

```
x.full_8_char_byte[0] = 0x7E;
x.full_8_char_byte[1] = 0xFF;
```

**the output I get is:**

```
�   ~ 
255   126 
FF   7E

~   ~ 
126   126 
7E   7E

0   0
```

Similar thing happens when I initialize `x.full_8_char_byte[0] to 0xFF`, my question is why the value in `x.ascii_7_bits_word_1` and `x.parity_bit_word_1` did not reflected per change in `x.full_8_char_byte[1]`?

Comment: Those `bit_word` members are all in an union, each of them represents same memory. Those `bit_word` members should be inside a `struct` that is inside that union to group them together.

Comment: what @KamilCuk said, plus there's no guarantee about padding of bit fields, so a portable solution can't be done with a union ... just provide macros / (inline) functions to access the individual bits using some masking instead.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, it worked correctly when I declared ascii_7_bits_word_0, parity_bit_word_0, ascii_7_bits_word_1, parity_bit_word_1 inside a struct in that union. But why it did not worked in the previous kinda declaration, I still did not get it?

Comment: union can hold only one of ALL it's members, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union , not first and all the the rest.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, actually you should have written this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t full_8_char_byte[2];
    uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_0 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
    uint8_t parity_bit_word_0 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
    uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_1 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
    uint8_t parity_bit_word_1 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
} ip_char_t;
```

The comments suggest you expect the 4 bitfield members to map the bits of the first array member. That won't work, because **all** members of a `union` are alternative possible contents, which also means every member will be placed at the very beginning. What you probably meant to write instead is

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t full_8_char_byte[2];
    struct {
        uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_0 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
        uint8_t parity_bit_word_0 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
        uint8_t ascii_7_bits_word_1 : 7; /* another way of representing LSP 7 ASCII bits */
        uint8_t parity_bit_word_1 : 1;   /* another way of representing MSP parity bit */
    };
} ip_char_t;
```

So this union can *either* contain your array *or* a struct with bitfields.

---

Note that this doesn't solve your problem in a portable way: There are no strict guarantees about how your bitfield will be arranged, see Leushenko's comment for details! For solving this problem portably, you can for example provide macros to access the individual bits, e.g.

```
typedef uint8_t ip_char_t[2];

#define ascii_7_bits_word(x,i) ((x)[i] & 0x7f)
#define parity_bit_word(x,i) ((x)[i] >> 7)
```

Or, if you also need to write to the bits or want to enforce type safety, write (inline) functions instead.

Comment: There *are* guarantees about padding of bitfield structures. C11 6.7.2.1p11 "shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit". The *order* of the packing and the size of the units is implementation-defined, but that is still predictable and must be documented by your compiler (if you don't know the value of `CHAR_BIT` for your platform, take a step back before playing with bits...). Within a unit, the order of bitfields is also only important if the value needs to be reinterpreted as something else (OK, in this particular case it does; in most cases bit-order is meaningless in C).

Comment: @Leushenko well, that was imprecise indeed, still you can't write code like this and expect it to behave as intended on any system. Changed the text a bit to just refer your comment, explaning it all in detail would IMHO be a bit too much for an answer here.